# Trying to set initial state of a react component based on the data I receive from an api call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning react and typescript and building a small application(guess a word game like hangman where u get 5 tries to guess the word) which makes an api call and gets the words from it. I build the array of words from the data and get a random word from that array and render that word on the dom.

I wrote a small app which is a word guess game with a react ui. I had an array words in a constant file and i was importing that array. I was passing that array into a method which returns a random word from the array. I was setting initial state based of the word returned. Now I am trying to extend that app by making an api call and rendering the word which i get back from the api call. I am hard time setting initial state of the app.

I tried creating a variable words and setting to an empty array of type any. I am adding that variable to the constructor, I am making an api call in componentwillmount hook and updating that array with the returned from the api call. Which i am passing into my randomword method to get a word to set the initial state, but i am getting a following error message

Array is empty

```
interface LetterType {
  letter: string
  disabled: boolean
}

interface State {
  alphabet: string
  letters: LetterType[]
  guessedLetters: Set<string>
  guessedTheWord: boolean
  guessesLeft: number
  word: LetterType[]
}


class App extends Component<{}, State> {
  words :any[];
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props)
    this.state = this.initialState()
    this.words = []
    this.selectLetter = this.selectLetter.bind(this)
    this.startNewGame = this.startNewGame.bind(this)
    this.addKeyPressListener()
  }

//method to set initial state

initialState(): State {
    const alphabet: string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    const letters: LetterType[] = Array.from(alphabet).map(letter => ({
      letter,
      disabled: false
    }))


//this is were i am getting a error message because when initial state is //called in constructor at that time array is still empty
// I can't figure out a better way to get data here from the api call

const word: LetterType[] = Array.from(this.randomWord(this.words)).map(
      letter => ({
        letter,
        disabled: false
       })
    )

    const guessedLetters: Set<string> = new Set()
    const guessesLeft: number = 5
    const guessedTheWord: boolean = false

    return {
      alphabet,
      letters,
      this.word,
      guessedLetters,
      guessesLeft,
      guessedTheWord
    }
  }

// making a get request. I was able to log the results from the get request
   componentMount(){
    axios.get('api/url')
      .then(response => response)
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.words =  result.data.split('\na')
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  }

//this method is called in the initialState to return the random word
  randomWord(words: any[] ): string {
    return words[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
    ].toUpperCase()
  }


  selectLetter(selectedLetter: string): void {
    this.updateGameStatus(this.state, selectedLetter)
  }


  updateGameStatus(state: State, selectedLetter: string): void {
    if (state.guessesLeft > 0 && !state.guessedTheWord) {
      const nextState: State = { ...state }
      const alreadyGuessedLetter: boolean = state.guessedLetters.has(
        selectedLetter
      )

      if (!alreadyGuessedLetter) {
        nextState.guessedLetters.add(selectedLetter)
        const letter: LetterType | undefined = nextState.letters.find(
          letter => letter.letter === selectedLetter
        )

        if (letter) {
          letter.disabled = true
        }
      }

      const guessedTheWord: boolean = nextState.word
        .filter(letter => !['-', ' '].includes(letter.letter))
        .every(letter => nextState.guessedLetters.has(letter.letter))

      const lettersFoundInWord: boolean =
        nextState.word.filter(letter => letter.letter === selectedLetter)
          .length > 0

      if (guessedTheWord) {
        nextState.guessedTheWord = true
      } else if (!alreadyGuessedLetter && !lettersFoundInWord) {
        nextState.guessesLeft--
      }

      nextState.word.forEach(letter =>
        letter.letter === selectedLetter ? (letter.disabled = true) : ''
      )

      this.setState(nextState)
    }
  }

  startNewGame(): void {
    this.setState(this.initialState())
  }

  addKeyPressListener(): void {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
      const letter: string = event.key.toUpperCase()

      if (this.state.alphabet.includes(letter)) {
        this.selectLetter(letter)
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Word
          word={this.state.word}
          guessedTheWord={this.state.guessedTheWord}
        />
        <div className="footer">
          <GuessesLeft guessesLeft={this.state.guessesLeft} />
          <GameResult
            guessedTheWord={this.state.guessedTheWord}
            guessesLeft={this.state.guessesLeft}
          />
          <NewWord onClick={this.startNewGame} />
        </div>
        <p className="sr-only">
          Welcome to play word guess game. Try to guess the word from the given
          category. Use keyboard to guess the letters.
        </p>
        <Alphabet letters={this.state.letters} onClick={this.selectLetter} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Array is empty

Comment: Did you mean to type `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Yes, I meant to type componendDidMount. Good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component is rendered, the constructor runs *first*. Your constructor calls `this.initialState()`, and that point `this.words` is still an empty array. When `componentDidMount` runs, as you've seen it'll fetch the data you need, but this fetch is asynchronous. Before the fetch completes, you need to render your component in a "data is loading" state, and when it's complete you need to finish your initialization and re-render of the content with this data.

So first of all, your `initialState` method shouldn't expect to be able to initialize word yet. Instead, set your state's `word` property to `null` or something like that. Then, in your `render` method, you'll be able to see that and know that you need to render something for users to know they need to wait for the game to finish loading:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.word) {
    return <div className="spinner">Loading. Please wait...</div>;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now you'll change your fetch callback so it sets the component's state, allowing it to finish initializing and re-render:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('api/url')
    .then(
      (result) => {
        const words = result.data.split('\na');
        const word = this.randomWord(words);
        this.setState({ word });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `initialState` method's return, you have `this.word` in there. That's certainly an error:

```js
  return {
    alphabet,
    letters,
    this.word,  // <-- This should just be `word`?
    guessedLetters,
    guessesLeft,
    guessedTheWord
  }
```

You also haven't bound `this` to the `initialState` method, so it probably doesn't have reliable access to the `this` that you expect. You have several methods that rely on the component's `this` but which haven't been bound in the constructor.

If I were you, I'd move your `initialState`, and `randomWord` methods above the component and use them as utility functions, rather than part of the component. You can pass them `words` to perform the calculations. I'd also try to move your `updateGameStatus` function above the component and just pass the data between. This isn't strictly required, just my opinion.

I also suggest that you move `this.words` into `this.state`. Your `this.words` *is* state. It belongs in the proper React `state` object.

This will fix your next problem. In your `componentDidMount` call, where you're trying to synchronously set `this.words`, you instead need to use React's `this.setState` method to asynchronously store your data:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/url')
      .then(response => response)
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            words: result.data.split('\na')
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  }
```

This should get you a lot closer to getting things working. Let me know how it goes. Good luck. It's a good project to practice React.